# PHP Variable Subclass and Accessing Parent Methods

Tags: php, oop, scope

This seems like a poor design model, but I'm going to ask anyhow.
I'd like to access parent methods from a variably selected child class. 
In this example, $db can't be found.

```
class car {
    function __construct(){
        $db = doSomethingGetDBObj();
        global $db; $this->db = $db;
    }
}

class engine extends car {

    var $valve;
    function whichValve( $which ){
        $this->valve = new $which();
        var_dump( $this->valve->motion() );
    }
}

class valve1 extends engine {
    function motion(){
        return( parent::$db->GetRow("query for valve 1") );
    }
}

class valve2 extends engine {   
    function motion(){
        return( parent::$db->GetRow("query for valve 2") );
    }
}

$drive = new engine();
$drive->whichValve( "valve2" );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't access the superglobals to get the DB object. Instead, pass in into the constructor.

I've added a `protected` `$db` property to the class, which means it can't be accessed outside the class (but descendants can access it).

Then, in the child classes you can access the `$db` property with `$this->db`, since the class is a descendant of `car`.

Some other minor suggestions:

- I'd suggest upper casing the first letter of the class name
- There's no need for brackets around the return statements
- Instead of passing the class name to `whichValve`, pass a constructed object (it's much easier to debug the code this way)

```php
class car {
    protected $db;

    function __construct($db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }
}

class engine extends car {
    protected $valve;

    function whichValve( $which ){
        $this->valve = new $which();
        var_dump( $this->valve->motion() );
    }
}

class valve1 extends engine {
    function motion(){
        return $this->db->GetRow("query for valve 1");
    }
}

class valve2 extends engine {   
    function motion(){
        return $this->db->GetRow("query for valve 2");
    }
}
```

Comment: This whole idea came from how WordPress handles plugins. I wanted to play around with installable extensions (for a custom app) that would all use common methods (getConfiguration, setConfiguration, etc.). In my example, the valves are the plugins. But reading your explanation, it seems I have more work to do, learning about scope and protection, first. Thank you for taking the time to document this stuff for me. This is a great crash course.

Answer (score 0):

The `parent` keyword is for accessing parent's method when there is local overrided ones. You can use `$this->db` to access the db attributes even when it is created in parent class.